# Making two divs in separate containers align always

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two DIVs which are in flex box of row wrap.
So in that I have two buttons which I want to be aligned always.

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container {
  flex: 1;
  
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.container> * {
  flex: 1;
}
button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">


  <div class="container">
    <h2>
        Container 1
    </h2>
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
    </div>
    <button>
      Click me
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>
        Container 2
    </h2>
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test and this is a long text to wrap around. So let it be</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
    </div>
    <button>
      Click me
    </button>
    <div class="more-container">
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In mobile resolution it should look like

[image]

In Lesser resolution it should look like
[image]

In Desktop
[image]

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/d69jcpnz/

Comment: You could use `@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) { ... }` in your css

Comment: It should be fluid. I dont know heights of both elements

Comment: By removing the `min-width: 300px;` in the container, it works...

Comment: This is not possible with flexbox (or an other layout method for that matter). There is no CSS method of aligning elements that do not share a common parent. You need javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Try that bro

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap; /*modification here*/
  justify-content: center;
}
.container {
  flex: 1;
  
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.container> * {
  flex: 1;
}
button {
  width: 100%;
}


/*add here*/
@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
  .main-container {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is working for me. Also not sure I understood what you did there apart from nowrap and wrap

Comment: I wanted it to work like displayed in the images. Buttons should align side by side. And it should be fluid.

Answer (score 0):

ok sry bro i didn't understood your goal, try this :

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container {
  flex: 1;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.container> * {
  flex: 1;
}
button {
  position: relative; /* position changed */
  width: 100%;
}
button.first { /* added style here */
  top: 5.65rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">


  <div class="container">
    <h2>
        Container 1
    </h2>
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
    </div>
    <button class="first"> <!-- added class here -->
      Click me
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>
        Container 2
    </h2>
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test and this is a long text to wrap around. So let it be</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
    </div>
    <button>
      Click me
    </button>
    <div class="more-container">
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the result is similar to your desired result.

is this ok like that ?

Comment: No hardcoding heights or positions doesnt fix. Even here it breaks in second image. https://jsfiddle.net/vinodgubbala/d69jcpnz/2/ decresing column splitter and see it.